# Span cursor not changing

Tags: javascript, html

I've got the following SPAN that contains another SPAN, which was added dynamically.

I am changing the cursor of the span, but it's still the default cursor, can it not be changed?

```html
<span class="content" id="message" contenteditable="true">
     This is a sample message <span class="nonEditable" style="cursor: pointer;">&lt;#TimeOfDay&gt; <span onclick="removePlaceholder(this)"/>
      <span class="closeTag">X</span>
</span>
</span>
```

This is the code that adds the HTML to the SPAN

```
function pasteHtmlAtCaret(html) {

    var btnValue = html.value;
    //var span = " <span class='nonEditable tags'>" + btnValue + "<span class='testing' cursor='pointer'></span>X</span> ";
    var span = '<span class="nonEditable" style="cursor: pointer" ><#' + btnValue + '> <span onclick=removePlaceholder(this)></span><span class="closeTag">X</span></span> ';

    var sel, range;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        // IE9 and non-IE
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();

            // Range.createContextualFragment() would be useful here but is
            // non-standard and not supported in all browsers (IE9, for one)
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.innerHTML = span;
            var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
            while ((node = el.firstChild)) {
                lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
            }
            range.insertNode(frag);

            // Preserve the selection
            if (lastNode) {
                range = range.cloneRange();
                range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                range.collapse(true);
                sel.removeAllRanges();
                sel.addRange(range);
            }
        }
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        // IE < 9
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(span);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, if you see the Demo snippet!! What are trying to do? What's the exact problem?!

Comment: It works as expected

Comment: It works correctly. With the info you have written, I only can imaginate the class "nonEditable" could set cursor to default with "!important". Have you checked that?

Comment: I've updated the question - the issue is when I click the button to add the span

Comment: That's when the cursor doesn't change